# Sort my ojects which are parsed from json data

Tags: java, android, comparable

My Android client get server JSON response as follows:

```
{"students":[{"id":1,"name":"John","age":12},
             {"id":2,"name":"Thmas","age":13}
             {"id":3,"name":"Merit","age":10}
             ...]}
```

My Android client code parses the JSON response to Java object by using [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

My corresponding Java classes:

```
public class StudentList{
  private List<Student> students;

  public List<Student> getStudents(){
    return students;   
  }
}

public class Student{
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
  public int getAge(){
    return age;
  }

}
```

Everything works fine for me at this point, I can successfully parse JSON data to my Java objects, like following:

```
//'jsonData' is the server responsed json data 
StudentList students = gson.fromJson(jsonData, StudentList.class)
```

Then, I would like to modify a bit to get the `students` (from `json` data) in an **alphabetic order, sorted by** student's `name`. I tried the following way: (I changed the `Student` class to implement the `Comparable<>` interface):

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>{
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
  public int getAge(){
    return age;
  }

  // Override compareTo(), sort by 'name'
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Student obj) {
    return this.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(obj.Name());      
  } 
}
```

With above modified `Student` class, I tried to parse the json data again :

```
//'jsonData' is the server responsed json data 
StudentList students = gson.fromJson(jsonData, StudentList.class)
```

But the resulted `students` are still the same as before the sorting. My sorting solution does not work at all. **Why?? Where am I wrong??**

Comment: Is there a reason not to just use [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with java. But I don't think you sorted the list. Try call the Collections.sort(students)?

Comment: you need to actually compare them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gson will not sort items in the list, it will still just add the items. You can sort the list after it's created using [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method:

```
java.util.Collections.sort(students);
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply implementing Comparable won't make your class be sorted; you've got to actually *do* something to sort it.

Comment: Thanks, could you please be more specific?

Comment: As a couple other answers have shown, Collections.sort() would be a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just because your class is `Comparable` does not make every collection automatically sort itself. You have to tell a particular collection to sort using the natural orderering, by using something like `Collections.sort(students);`